# Chrome DevTools Protocol: Unable to communicate with Google Chrome 112 via Websocket

Tags: google-chrome, protocols, devtools, cdp

1、My Google Chrome version is 114,  Using commands：chrome.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222, open chrome, and using htpp://127.0.0.1:9222/json get webSocketDebuggerUrl(ws://localhost:9222/devtools/browser/b0b8a4fb-bb17-4359-9533-a8d9f3908bd8), unable to use URL for WS connection by Local WS Client Tools.
2、If change the Google Browser version to 104, I can establish a WS connection through the webSocketDebuggerUrl by Local WS Client Tools.

I guess it was caused by the browser version, but I believe that WS connection can be achieved by adding parameters, but I don't know how to do it.
Can you help me? Thank you.